# Preventing Parent From Firing Events When Child MouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `Grid` placed at the top of the `Window` in which inside of it there's an `Image` placed. The `Grid` is supposedly dragging the window with a `MouseDown` event.

However, whenever i want to fire a `MouseDown` event to the `Child Image` it doesn't work but, instead it fires the `Grid's`.

```
private void toggleTbr_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     this.DragMove();
}

private void leapTcb_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     e.Handled = true;
     //my code
}
```

As you see i tried `e.Handled = true;` but it changes nothing, then i thought of trying of using `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` instead of `MouseLeftButtonDown` but, still the same.

What am i doing wrong here, or how to prevent the `Grid` from triggering?

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="toggleTbr" MouseLeftButtonDown="toggleTbr_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid x:Name="leapTcb_" Height="21" Width="26">
        <Image x:Name="leapTcb" MouseLeftButtonDown="leapTcb_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Image.Background>
                <ImageBrush Source="Resources/leap_1.png"/>
            </Image.Background>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Which event is raised from Child Image?

Comment: @Sankarann `LeapTcb_MouseLeftButtonDown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code works fine, but if it isn't enough you can try using this:

```
IsHitTestVisible="True"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Image element has no Background property, instead, set the Source property directly at the image element.

`<Image x:Name="leapTcb" Source="Resources/leap_1.png" MouseLeftButtonDown="leapTcb_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>`

However you made this running, but with the specified change it behaves like you want, at least on my machine.

Comment: yes, i actually made that change too for a better perf.

Answer (score 0):

Use this this is working my side

```
<Grid x:Name="toggleTbr" MouseLeftButtonDown="toggleTbr_MouseLeftButtonDown" Background="Red">
        <Grid x:Name="leapTcb_" Height="21" Width="26">
<Image x:Name="leapTcb" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="leapTcb_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Image.Background>
                <ImageBrush Source="Resources/leap_1.png"/>
            </Image.Background>
        </Image>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```